# Behavior of AdRequest.addKeyword() in AdMob API

Tags: android, admob

Does `addKeyword()` whitelist or blacklist the keywords added? The documentation doesn't state which.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - **whitelist**.

Longer answer - AdMob front-fill ads currently aren't using this signal. We pass these keywords onto AdSense backfill ads if you have those enabled, but they may not use that signal either. So using addKeyword has little effect if any right now, and therefore isn't generally used.

Comment: That's too bad. It would be nice to provide ads which are similar to the theme of my app and so would more likely interest my users.

Comment: strongly agree with @Code-Guru . too bad that they are not used.